# Does a "dupe" on another (non-SE/SO) site warrant a vote to close?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

On Stack Overflow a user asked the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9867821/opencl-slower-than-opengl

As noted by user [gpu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/228119/gpu), this exact question has been asked on Nvidia's forums as well: http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=225898

He goes on to state "Vote to close". Not taking into account the quality of this particular question, I would say that this is a bit much. The OP is, in my opinion, fully within his right to ask the same question on a different Q&A-site or forum if he wishes to do so.

So my question is: If the question asked on SO is a duplicate of a question asked on a different (non-SE/SO) site, does that warrant a vote to close (as duplicate)?

I would say it does not, but would like to hear your thoughts on this.

Comment: @TheEstablishment Ah yes, that is in essence a dupe. I didn't find that one. Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No, it does not. You can't even close something as a cross-SE-site duplicate either (unless you count migrating it then closing it as a dupe at the target site), so there's no sense in closing an SE question as a duplicate of its repost in a totally different site.

It's up to somebody to repost their content on different sites across the Internet if they don't mind or consider the inconvenience and the content duplication, but Stack Exchange is Stack Exchange, and we're really only interested in our content.

Comment: See, now that sounds perfectly logical and in line with what I thought. I just wondered if I had missed some (admittedly strange) SO/SE policy. Thanks.

Comment: I myself have flagged two posts that users have asked simultaneously on two separate SE sites.  Was this the right thing to do, or is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: @K.G.: Yes, you flagged correctly. We handle this by migrating one to the other, then closing it there, as mentioned in my answer. I don't believe there is any better way to do so, at least not yet...