# Is cross posting between MSDN and Stack Overflow frowned on?

Tags: discussion, cross-posting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it wrong to ask the same question elsewhere?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22657/is-it-wrong-to-ask-the-same-question-elsewhere)

I have a question that I [asked on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/vsx/thread/74175e24-9f3f-465c-8216-6e2b099e9df9).

I have not gotten an answer on MSDN, and I am wondering if it is frowned on to cross post it to Stack Overflow.

What is the general policy on cross posting from (and to) other Q and A sites if the question is my own?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22657/is-it-wrong-to-ask-the-same-question-elsewhere - I also recently addressed a similar issue where somebody thought it *was* frowned upon, when it isn't http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126920/does-a-dupe-on-another-non-se-so-site-warrant-a-vote-to-close/126921#126921

Answer (score 6):

I've done this before with other sites, most often ServerFault and a vendor site (E.G. VMWare's forums)

If you're doing it because you posted in *one* place first and aren't getting your answer, by all means post in the second place. If you're doing this *for every question*, then, well... don't.

**Please make sure that when you get an answer in one place, you update the question on the other site!**

Comment: Just a clarification in case anybody misreads what you wrote: cross-posting between Server Fault and a vendor's site is fine. Cross-posting between Server Fault and another Stack Exchange site is not good though - you shouldn't cross-post between SE sites.

Comment: Yes, thanks @nhinkle, that is what I meant.

Answer (score 5):

The reason Stack Overflow exists is because it's *better than* forums like MSDN.  So yeah, if you've posted a (good) question on MSDN and haven't gotten an answer, then by all means post it here; and consider coming here first next time :)

And as unhandled exception says, be sure to post the answer on MSDN if you get one here as a courtesy to the next guy.