# Cross-posting between SO and vendor sites

Tags: discussion, questions

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is it wrong to ask the same question elsewhere?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22657/is-it-wrong-to-ask-the-same-question-elsewhere)
>   [Does a "dupe" on another (non-SE/SO) site warrant a vote to close?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126920/does-a-dupe-on-another-non-se-so-site-warrant-a-vote-to-close)

Is it generally acceptable to cross-post vendor specific questions between a vendor's support forum and SO (assuming the question meets SO's guidelines)? I understand some vendors (like Microsoft) have personnel that monitor SO and actively participate in the tags related to their products.

In the case where a vendor doesn't actively participate in our community, questions regarding their products are typically left to the community to answer from their experience (which is great). In the case of smaller companies or newly released products, these questions are going to be much harder to answer because the number of people exposed to the technology is likely to be fewer.

Here's my specific situation:

I've been playing around with the MVVM functionality included in the latest release of Kendo UI, and ran into some problems with it yesterday. I asked a question on the Kendo forums and then [cross-posted it on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003589/nested-viewmodel-dependent-methods-dont-work) in hopes that someone may be able to point out something simple (I expected to have a *duh* moment since I'm fairly new to Javascript), and besides the SO community is the greatest!

I haven't received any negative feedback on cross-posting the question, but figured I'd double check that what I did was acceptable. The question has only been viewed 23 times, so I didn't think that was a good enough sample of the community to apply the "silence is acceptance" rule.

What are your thoughts?

---

On a positive note, it looks like my question is the 5<sup>th</sup> google result when searching for "Kendo MVVM", so I guess it can't be all bad.