# Is it OK to ask a question about RDF, SPARQL etc on both Stack Overflow and semanticweb.com?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, duplicate-questions

The website https://answers.semanticweb.com looks very similar to the Stack Overflow sites and is about aspects of the semantic web. Thus there is quite some overlap to questions asked on Stack Overflow about RDF, SPARQL, OWL and other topics.

From the side of Stack Overflow, would it be OK to ask the same or a very similar question on Stack Overflow that has already been asked at semanticweb.com?

Comment: *Related:* [Why is cross-posting wrong (on an external site)?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Semantic Web is nothing to do with Stack Exchange. So whether someone posts there or not is no concern of ours.

Answer (score 5):

I don't like cross-posting the same question to multiple sites.

When I take some time to write an answer to a question, just to find out that the *exact same question* already has an answer with pretty much the same content, then I feel like I wasted my time.

And if someone posts the same question on multiple sites at the same time, then chances are that *several* people will waste their time like this.

In my opinion, the *least* that you can do in such a situation is to put a short disclaimer at the end saying "I also posted this question [over on example.com](http://www.example.com/)." This way I can at least check if the answer I'm about to write was already given.