# Should I refrain from posting the same question on different websites?

Tags: discussion, questions

Say I'm in a hurry and I really need help to fix some code. I want to reach many people and get the best answer as soon as possible.

In this situation I would probably copy and paste the same question on a few good websites like Stack Overflow and [The Code Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Project).

Are there any consequences I might face for doing this, being reported for example, or is it perfectly acceptable and maybe pretty common?

Comment: isnt that question specifically asking about crossover posting within the stack exchange site?

Comment: But that question answer is somewhat relates to your question

Comment: Related (possible duplicate): [Why is cross-posting wrong (on an external site)?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141823/262755)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In this situation I would probably copy and paste the same question on a few good websites like **stack overflow** and **code project**

(Emphasis mine)

It is your question, so if you want to post it on an SE site and multiple other sites you are fine.

Don't just cross-post on the SE network of sites since that is considered abusive use of the SE sites. This question explains that situation: [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/).

Comment: When posting between SE and elsewhere I think it would also be etiquette to include links to the other postings